# How to specify degree of rounding in "rboxes" package?

Tags: metapost

Consider this `test.mp`:

```
prologues:=3;
input rboxes;
beginfig(1);
rboxit.box1(btex hello world etex);
box1.dx=3mm; box1.dy=2mm;
box1.c=(8.8cm,4.5cm);
drawboxed(box1);
endfig;
end
```

It yields this:

[image]

How to make corners less rounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is [`rbox_radius`](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/metapost/base/rboxes.mp?revision=2554&view=markup#l15).

Example with MetaFun (sorry I never use plain MetaPost).

```
\startMPinclusions
  input rboxes;
\stopMPinclusions

\startMPpage
  interim rbox_radius := 2bp; % default 8bp
  rboxit.box1(btex hello world etex);
  box1.dx=3mm; box1.dy=2mm;
  box1.c=(8.8cm,4.5cm);
  drawboxed(box1);
\stopMPpage
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The same for `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{input rboxes; beginfig(1);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
rbox_radius := 2bp;
rboxit.box1(btex hello world etex);
box1.dx=3mm; box1.dy=2mm;
box1.c=(8.8cm,4.5cm);
drawboxed(box1);        
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```